# How to capture error and roll back transaction one time in Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Suppose I have more than one SQL to change the data in database in a SP. I create a transaction at the beginning, then commit or roll back the transaction at the end. What I did is something like:

```
declare @HasError bit
BEGIN TRANSACTION
set @HasError = 0;

Insert into Table1....
if(@@ERROR>0)
   set @HasError = 1;

Insert into Table2....
if(@@ERROR>0)
   set @HasError = 1;

Insert into Table3....
if(@@ERROR>0)
   set @HasError = 1;

...

if @HasError = 1
 Rollback;
else
  Commit;
```

It's working fine. But need to capture error for each U/I/D sql. Is there anyway I can know if there is any error at the end for only one piece of code like

```
if(@@ERROR>0)
   set @HasError = 1;
if @HasError = 1
 Rollback;
else
  Commit;
```

No need to do so many error detection for each U/I/D sql?

Comment: Have you looked at [try/catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976(v=sql.100).aspx)?

Comment: Aside: You could always replace `@HasError` with something like `declare @SavedError as Int = 0;` and then scatter `set @SavedError = case when @SavedError = 0 then @@Error else @SavedError end` around.  That has the possible benefit of retaining the first error for logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I follow the question, but something like this might work for you

```
BEGIN TRAN
   BEGIN TRY
        Insert into Table1....
        Insert into Table2....
        Insert into Table3....
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        RETURN
    END CATCH
COMMIT TRAN
```